# PYTHON AND IBPY: UNEXPECTED EOF WHILE PARSING ; I can't figure it out

Tags: python

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message 
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract 
from ib.ext.Order import Order 

def error_handler(msg):
    print ("Server Error:", msg)

def server_handler(msg):
    print ("Server Msg:", msg.typeName, "-", msg)

def create_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, prim_exch, curr):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.m_symbol = symbol
    contract.m_secType = sec_type
    contract.m_exchange = exch
    contract.m_primaryExch = prim_exch
    contract.m_currency = curr
    return contract


def create_order(order_type, quantity, action):
    order = Order()
    order.m_orderType = order_type
    order.m_totalQuantity = quant`enter code here`ity
    order.m_action = action
    return order


if __name__ == "__main__":   
    client_id = 100
    order_id = 1086
    port = 7496
    tws_conn = None    
    try:
        tws_conn = Connection.create(port=port,clientId=client_id)
        tws_conn.connect()
        tws_conn.register(error_handler, 'Error')
        tws_conn.registerAll(server_handler)
        aapl_contract = create_contract('AAPL', 
                                        'STK', 
                                        'SMART', 
                                        'SMART', 
                                        'USD')
        aapl_order = create_order('MKT', 100, 'SELL')
        tws_conn.placeOrder(order_id, aapl_contract, aapl_order)
        if tws_conn is not None:
            tws_conn.disconnect()
```

---

unexpected EOF while parsing line 49`

---

Please help me to sort out this problem, I tried many times to add parenthesis at the end or somewhere else, however I could not find the appropriate solution for that kind of problem.

Comment: I think there is code missing at the bottom. For example, the `try` seems to have no `except`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are using `try` without `except` block.

Comment: So, what is the full solution ? Could you specify please.

Comment: @DANRich Just remove the `try:`, and unindent everything after that. or you can add except block if you want to handle errors.